# Installing SQL Server on Windows 10 issues

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have installed the Window 10 on my system. I am trying to install Microsoft SQL server on my machine.

In the between of installation SQL Server asks for .Net framework 3.5. When I try to install .Net framework 3.5 it throws an exception like.

> The referenced assembly is not installed on your system

I've searched on Google about this issue but can't find any solution. 
Please if anyone know real problem behind this, please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Win10 in 32-bit or 64-bit? I also found this link (http://winaero.com/blog/fix-net-framework-install-error-0x800736b3-14003/) which perhaps can help you.

Comment: @MattiasLindberg Window 10 64 bit Sql server 2014 .
Thanks for the link but same issue still exsist. Using this way i found 140003 error in command prompt.

Comment: Is this not the same problem: http://superuser.com/questions/860791/windows-10-net-3-5-installation#_=_